# Embed Bootstrap 3 Based Grid System Only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have an existing website which I need to add a grid based layout to only within the main content area and not in the nav bar or footer section. The problem I am encountering is that when I use the bootstrap 3 customization tool and de-select everything except the grid system option and then add the resultant bootstrap.css file it changes my pages typography, element sizes, etc and throws the entire layout of the page out of wack.

Does anyone have any advice on how to embed a grid system like Bootstrap 3's grid system into my page and force it to only work on child elements of a div with the class "grid" added to it (or some similar CSS selector). I get the feeling that trying to embed the entire Bootstrap 3 grid system into my page will be unnecessary and that it could be as simple as defining a range of CSS classes such as .row, .col-1, .col-2, etc but I don't know exactly where to start.

NB: The responsive capabilities of the grid system aren't required but would be good if they can still be used by using col-md, col-sm, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can override the bootstrap 3 grid classes to its core stylesheet (bootstrap.css) to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work out what I needed to do. I reviewed the Bootstrap.css file and extracted all the classes to do with the .content, .row, and .col-* styles, I then embedded them in my own stylesheet and tweaked them to suit my required use case for columns and it did exactly what I needed.